# "Boot Camp only support 64-bit Windows 8 or later" when attempting to install Windows 10

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp, windows

I tried to install Windows 10 on my MacBook Pro 2015 running macOS Sierra, but I am getting a message on Boot Camp saying

> Boot Camp only supports 64-bit Windows 8 or later installation on this platform. Please use an ISO file for 64-bit Windows 8 or later installation.

I downloaded the ISO from Microsoft's website named "Win10_1703_English_x64.iso".

Comment: When it prompts you for the ISO file, does it automatically find one, and does the name of the file it finds match exactly with the one you downloaded?

Answer (score 2):

Version 1703, Creators, is the wrong one, use the Anniversary version with 1607 in the name is the correct version. After installing Win10, you can upgrade to 1703.